# VHDL Structural

Tags: vhdl, hdl

Hi can anyone help me with a VHDL question. I'm trying some practical structural programming and wanted to start with a simple half adder. Heres my code

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
```

--XOR DESCRITION

```
entity xor_2 is
    port (a, b : in std_logic;
        f : out std_logic );
end xor_2;

Architecture func of xor_2 is
begin
    f <= a xor b;
end func;
```

--AND DESCRIPTION

```
entity and_2 is
    port (a, b : in std_logic;
            f : out std_logic);
end and_2;

architecture func of and_2 is
begin
    f1 <= a and b;
end func;
```

--HALF ADDER DESCRIPTION

```
entity struct_1 is
    port ( a, b : in std_logic;
            s, c : out std_logic);
end struct_1;

architecture struct_1 of struct_1 is

component xor_2 is
    port( a, b : in std_logic;
            f : out std_logic);
end component;

component and_2 is
    port( a, b : in std_logic;
            f : out std_logic);
end component;

begin
    g1 : xor_2 port map (a, b, s);
    g2 : and_2 port map (a, b, c);

end struct_1;
```

I'm using the Quartus II design software and I keep getting the following warning when running testing:

```
Error (10482): VHDL error at Struct_1.vhd(15): object "std_logic" is used but
not declared
```

I've looked at various sites and papers to understand what I'm doing but each place I've visited gives slightly different details and I've yet to find one that actually works for comparison. I'm OK with getting it to work with a data flow approach but no structural.
Please lads and ladies help a man out here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `std_logic` type is not visible. It needs to be made visible by a library/use clause:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```

Of course I see that you already have such a clause. The scope of it is not as large as you might think. In VHDL a library/use clause only applies to the following entity, architecture, package or package body. An architecture automatically inherits the library/use clauses from its entity but not the other way around. A package body automatically inherits the library/use clauses from its package but not the other way around.

I guess you have put everything in the same file Struct_1.vhd? In that case only xor_2 entity/architecture sees the library/use clause for ieee.std_logic_1164. You need to add it above every entity. Also a good coding practice is to only have one entity/architecture pair per file.

Comment: Hi Kraigher, thanks for the excellet reply. Yes you are right I was assuming that  declaring the library IEEE was like decliaring a C header file.